# NullPointerException if empty stream is empty

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I need to define max minutes from set my code

```
 carWashBoxSet.
                stream().
                filter(p -> p.getOrderTime() != null).
                map(t -> t.getOrderTime()).
                max(Date::compareTo).
                get().
                getMinutes();
```

The problem is if carWashBoxSet empty i get null pointer exeption, is it any to use smth like `stream.ifNonEpty().Orelse()` ?

Comment: To be sure: you get a NPE if carWashBoxSet is null or if it's empty?

Comment: why not check for null before? or Optional.ofNullable(carWashBoxSet)

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using the outdated `Date` class and you should definitely avoid its deprecated `getMinutes` method. It’s deprecated because it’s unreliable. It’s not clear from the context, but maybe `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` or even `LocalTime` or `LocalDateTime` may be better choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i highly recommend to not use `.get()` without `.isPresent()`, because when the optional is empty, you will create a NoSuchElementException.

To bypass this i would map the `getMinutes()` at the end, and add an `.orElse()` or `.orElseGet()` depending on what you expect as an alternative.

```
carWashBoxSet.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getOrderTime() != null)
            .map(t -> t.getOrderTime())
            .max(Date::compareTo)
            .map(boxSet -> boxSet.getMinutes())
            .orElse(/*another value*/);
```

if you do not expect an alternative and want to just process this value somehow, without further usage  `.ifPresent()` can also be a good choice.

```
carWashBoxSet.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getOrderTime() != null)
            .map(t -> t.getOrderTime())
            .max(Date::compareTo)
            .map(boxSet -> boxSet.getMinutes())
            .ifPresent( minutes -> System.out.println(minutes));
```